# Map an Object to an array using react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, object

this object is taken from a form that has input, output and outputType which can change from number String and Boolean

I have created the mapped obj so that i can show it in a table without outputype but i also want to take it to an edit page where i need as an array listed at the bottom with its type

```
      const mapped = form.values.formValue.reduce((obj: ValueMaped, { input, outputType, output }) => {
    let parsedOutput: ValMap['output']

    switch (outputType) {
      case 'String':
        parsedOutput = output.toString()
        break

      case 'Number':
        parsedOutput = parseFloat(output.toString())
        break

      case 'Boolean':
        parsedOutput = Boolean(output)
        break
    }

    obj[input] = parsedOutput

    return obj
  }, {})
  onSave(mapped)
```

I have an obj = mapped im am getting the result as below

```
{
  valueA: 'sample value as string',
  valueB: 123,
  valueC: true
}
```

how can i map and convert it to an array as below

```
[
  { input: 'valueA', outputType: 'String', output: 'sample value as string' },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), we can map over the keys and values simultaneously:

```
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([input, output]) => ({ input, output, outputType: capitalize(typeof output) }));
```

I've also chosen to use a utility to capitalize the result from `typeof`:

```
function capitalize(s: string) { return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1); }
```

The output generated for your example object looks like

```
[{
  "input": "valueA",
  "output": "sample value as string",
  "outputType": "String"
}, {
  "input": "valueB",
  "output": 123,
  "outputType": "Number"
}, {
  "input": "valueC",
  "output": true,
  "outputType": "Boolean"
}]
```

```js
const obj = {
    valueA: "sample value as string",
    valueB: 123,
    valueC: true,
};

function capitalize(s) { return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1); }

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([input, output]) => ({ input, output, outputType: capitalize(typeof output) }));

console.log(result);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMBuAhgDYCuApgIIBcMARBAQLYAORZ+x5MBEM0ATgEswAc1oAabLkKkyAIRoBGAEwBmSbg6yAwjSj9ykgL4BuTJgBmJMMCiDwMYAWaCoxQQC8yACgg0BwiIAlBgw-GRQJPxgfADaAAwAugB0UCAAqszMZPzaPD4hANR8yRBEgsA+ikEmMEbmoJCw4RAkRLBoAPJIZLbJZGD6gmQQ3giIQcmMzt7escLMJFDicEuLUIkhKAB8MN7oMAtLKyBrx6tQ6wAqAJ7ZNE4ubuVe3lB3ZCAWF+shRkE1BrgCAgNjJIggETeFptKA1IA)

---

P.S. Consider using all-lowercase for the `outputType`:

```
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([input, output]) => ({ input, output, outputType: typeof output }));
```

It'll remove the need for extra code to capitalize it. You would then also need to update your switch statement to reflect this:

```
switch (outputType) {
    case 'string':
        parsedOutput = output.toString()
        break

    // ...
}
```